# keyboard shortcut using javascript not working

Tags: javascript

I am using `command + h` as a shortcut key in my website. It is not doing the function to be done. After I click something on the window only  it works flawlessly. Here is my code..

```
window.onkeydown = function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 72 && (event.metaKey == true)) { 
        //some function
    }
}
```

Somebody try to rectify . I have included this code only after the dom gets loaded

Comment: To handle keyboard shortcut, you should take a look to this library => https://github.com/jeresig/jquery.hotkeys

Comment: Cool library @ADreNaLiNe-DJ !

Comment: IMHO `window.onkeydown` event will obviously get fired only if your document is focused/clicked

Comment: @anu , so instead of keydown what can i use or can u tell any alternatives

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`window.onkeydown` will only work if it is focused. So on body load you should set focus.

```
<body onload="setFocus()">

function setFocus(){
  window.focus();
}
```

Working [DEMO HERE](https://jsbin.com/vikexatapi/edit?console,output)

Answer (score 0):

You could probably make it work with focusing the body on window load with `document.body.focus()` and attaching an event listener like this:

```
window.onload = function() {
  document.body.focus();
  document.addEventListener("keydown", keyDownFunction, false);
};

function keyDownFunction(event) {
  if(event.keyCode == 72 && (event.metaKey == true)) {
    alert("You hit the right keys.");
  }
}
```